# How to split excluding a specific string form in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm making an app that splits the markdown content like the one below into a string of '---' and displays it as a slide. However, even if there is table markdown as shown below, it is split together and an error occurs. How can I split only '---' as a string, excluding table markdown?

```
# Title

---

|hello|world|
|---|---|
|asd|zxc|
```

Comment: You can use `^---$` in regex to exclude pattern with three dashes.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a regex for the split, then you can adjust how you split.

For instance, if the `---` you want to split are always alone on their lines, then splitting off of `/^---$/gm` works well.

The `m` is a flag to tell the regex that it's in multiline mode - I.e. ^ and $ match to each individual line, rather than to the full string.

```js
const string = `# Title

---

|hello|world|
|---|---|
|asd|zxc|`;

console.log(string.split(/^---$/gm))
```